# Set UIImage to cover the screen for all device screens, xib file

Tags: ios, uiimage, autolayout, xib

I have a view controller and the UI for the view controller is represented through a xib file instead of main.storyboard. Here is how it looks like. As you can see I have an UIImage view that acts as a background image and is suppose to cover the whole screen. [image]

I am trying to add four constraints: Make all four spacing to the nearest neighbors equal to 0. But when I use the pin constraint option and set pin all sides to 0, it doesn't make the spacing to the nearest neighbor zero but gives me the following four constraints:

[image]

So then I tried to control drag from the uiimage to the edge of the frame but I can't do that either. How can I solve this issue?

Also forgot to mention an important thing. When I run the app there are black spaces in the top and bottom of the screen. So the UIImage does not cover the whole screen. Here is a picture while the app is running:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is launchscreen.**

> You need to check the launchscreen ,if it is not in correct format or
>   there is no launchscreen means this kind of problem will occurs .

Comment: then check with other resolution bro ,still you can't get means come here i will give you solution

Comment: It's not the resolution. I don't expect the correct solution. Just expect some ideas that can help me out.

Comment: @Harsh.C can you give me the screenshot of your screen while running ?

Comment: Yea adding that now.

Comment: @Harsh.C its not constraints problem

Comment: Oh okay. You know what it is then?

Comment: Okay going to add launch screen now. But I don't understand how launch screen affects my view.

Comment: @Harsh.C once you changed let me know :)

Comment: Yea sorry forgot to respond.